# How to receive OU values separately in different columns via powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

The powershell query I use to get the list of all the workstations registered in AD is on below:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -NotLike "*server*"} -Property * | Select-Object Name,SID,DistinguishedName,whenCreated,LastLogonDate | Export-CSV allworkstations2.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

An example of "DistinguishedName" is like:

```
CN=500-AV,OU=Workstations,OU=SecondOU,OU=ThirdOU,OU=FourthOU,DC=myDC1,DC=myDC2
CN=600-AV,OU=FirstOU,OU=SecondOU,OU=ThirdOU,OU=FourthOU,OU=FifthOU,DC=myDC1,DC=myDC2
```

Please note that the number of OU values for each workstation can differ, can't say it is always 4. **Edit:** Maximum number of OU a workstation can have is 5.

I need all the OU values separately, as different columns (OU1, OU2, ... etc). In Excel, I was using this formula below to receive all the OU values in separate columns:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(MID($B2,FIND(",OU=",$B2)+4,FIND(",DC=",$B2)-FIND(",OU=",$B2)-4),",OU=",REPT(" ",999)),(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*999+1,999))
```

What I want is to get the OU values in different columns directly from the powershell. I couldn't find out the correct syntax to update my query accordingly. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the version info:
[image]

**Edit2:** Example of expected output:

```
WorkstationName SID OU1          OU2      OU3     OU4      OU5 createdDate LastLogin
500-AV           X  Workstations SecondOU ThirdOU FourthOU null    1/1/2018   6/1/2018
600-AV           X  FirstOU      SecondOU ThirdOU FourthOU FifthOU 1/1/2018   6/1/2018
```

Comment: do you know the _maximum_ number of OUs that will be in the DN? if not, then you will need to calculate that. once you have the number, you can build a PSCustomObject with that many OUs, fill it with as many as exist for that DN, fill the extras with $Null, and move on to the next user account.

Comment: beat me to it @Lee_Dailey!

Comment: Maximum is 5 @Lee_Dailey

Comment: Could u please help me creating PSCustomObject you mentioned, I am not very experienced in powerhell @Lee_Dailey

Comment: `$dn -split ',' | ? {$_.Trim() -like 'ou=*'} | % {$_.Trim() -replace '^ou='}`?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Can you show an example of the expected output (with at least two different OU DN's as input)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen example output added

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers should I add it in the select statement?

Comment: Thanks. That means you're going to have completely misaligned columns unless every user account is nested at the exact same level of parent OUs, just FYI. The example you gave doesn't seem to reflect your actual directory structure (How can `OU=FourthOU` be at the root of the domain, yet still have `OU=FifthOU` as it's parent container in the second example?)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen added the distinguishedname for 600-AV as well. This is the structure provided to me, I don't have rights to modify it, just need to run a query on it to receive OUs in separate columns.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli - thank you for the added info. please see my answer ... i think it does what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

now that you clarified things a tad, i think this does what you want. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- creates two user objects to work with
  delete this when you are ready to work with your data set. [*grin*]
- iterates thru the user list
- splits the DistinguishedName to get the OUs
- makes the `$OuList` variable into an array even if there is only one OU
- builds a custom object with the anticipated max number of OUs
  you will need to determine that ahead of time.
- sends that object out to the `$Results` collection
- displays that collection

at that point, you have a collection that will gracefully export to a CSV file. [*grin*]

here's the code ...

```
$UserList = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = '111-AV'
        SID = '1-22-333'
        DistinguishedName = 'CN=111-AV,OU=SolitaryOU,DC=myDC1,DC=myDC2'
        DateCreated = '2011-11-11'
        LastLogon = '2019-08-11'
        }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = '500-AV'
        SID = '1234-5678-90'
        DistinguishedName = 'CN=500-AV,OU=Workstations,OU=SecondOU,OU=ThirdOU,OU=FourthOU,DC=myDC1,DC=myDC2'
        DateCreated = '2001-01-01'
        LastLogon = '2019-08-08'
        }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = '666-AV'
        SID = '777-888-999'
        DistinguishedName = 'CN=666-AV,OU=Servers,OU=SrvOu2,OU=SrvOu3,OU=SrvOu4,OU=SrvOu5,DC=myDC1,DC=myDC2'
        DateCreated = '1999-12-31'
        LastLogon = '2019-08-20'
        }
    )

$Results = foreach ($UL_Item in $UserList)
    {
    [array]$OuList = @($UL_Item.DistinguishedName.Split(',')).
        Where({$_ -match 'OU='}).
        ForEach({$_.Split('=')[-1]}).
        Trim()

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $UL_Item.ComputerName
        SID = $UL_Item.SID
        OU_1 = $OuList[0]
        OU_2 = $OuList[1]
        OU_3 = $OuList[2]
        OU_4 = $OuList[3]
        OU_5 = $OuList[4]
        DateCreated = $UL_Item.DateCreated
        LastLogon = $UL_Item.LastLogon
        }
    }

$Results
```

output to screen ...

```
ComputerName : 111-AV
SID          : 1-22-333
OU_1         : SolitaryOU
OU_2         : 
OU_3         : 
OU_4         : 
OU_5         : 
DateCreated  : 2011-11-11
LastLogon    : 2019-08-11

ComputerName : 500-AV
SID          : 1234-5678-90
OU_1         : Workstations
OU_2         : SecondOU
OU_3         : ThirdOU
OU_4         : FourthOU
OU_5         : 
DateCreated  : 2001-01-01
LastLogon    : 2019-08-08

ComputerName : 666-AV
SID          : 777-888-999
OU_1         : Servers
OU_2         : SrvOu2
OU_3         : SrvOu3
OU_4         : SrvOu4
OU_5         : SrvOu5
DateCreated  : 1999-12-31
LastLogon    : 2019-08-20
```

Comment: I think the key takeaway for the OP here is to not export to CSV until you've finished manipulating data - keep things in objects so that you can use them.

Comment: @Scepticalist - yep, that would seem more sensible ... but the OP may not have that choice. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: Looks great, just a quick question, you've set the values for each field manually here, how I can get those by using --> "Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -NotLike "*server*"} -Property * | Select-Object Name,SID,DistinguishedName,whenCreated,LastLogonDate"

Comment: I will need the $userList returning from get-adcomputer, right?

Comment: Yes, just assign your query to the variable $UserList instead of exporting to csv.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli - you will need to set the names for things like `$UL_Item.ComputerName` to what is in your data set. once you have that, you can simply address the items with the property names that your system uses.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey everything is awesome, except for some workstations having only one OU as "Disabled Computers". Example-> DistinguishedName : CN=myCN ,OU=Disabled Computers,DC=myDC1 ,DC=myDC2... It comes as OU1:d, OU2:i, OU3: s, OU4: a, OU5: b. can you test it please

Comment: please use this to see what I try to say: $UserList = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = '500-AV'
        SID = '1234-5678-90'
        DistinguishedName = 'CN=myCN,OU=Disabled Computers,DC=myDC1,DC=myDC2'
        DateCreated = '2001-01-01'
        LastLogon = '2019-08-08'
        }
    )

Comment: @ErayBalkanli - i see what you are talking about. let me fiddle with a single-ou test and see what i can come up with.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli - i found a quick, easy fix. [*grin*] i will modify the answer to include that ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks for your time and effort. Working well now. You helped a lot.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]